# How to get access to variable outside of its function

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['str'])) {
    fna();
} else { 
    fnb();
}

function fna(){
    // ...
    $result = 5;
}

function fnb(){
    // ... 
    $result = 9;
}

function fnc(){
    if ($result == 5){
        //error - undefined variable $result
    }
}
```

How can I get access to `$result` outside of `fna()` or `fnb()`?

Comment: Don't know what your are doing here... Maybe you should explain a little more

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I want the `$result ` variable inside `fnc()`. That's all.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, there is only one single `$result` variable. It's value is changed inside `fna()` or `fnb()`, depending on `$_GET['str']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how scope works in PHP: the variables named `$result` are all different instances, since they belong to the scopes of the functions in which they occur.

This is a good thing, and promotes good design.

You should `return` the value of your interest from `fna` and `fnb` instead of trying to use so-called side-effects. And then *pass* that value to your final function, so that it is clear it needs it. All this will make your code much more readable:

```
$result = isset($_GET['str']) ? fna() : fnb(); // <--- get return value

function fna(){
    return 5; // <--- return it
}

function fnb(){
    return 9;
}

function fnc($result){ // <--- what the function needs
    if ($result == 5){

    }
}

fnc($result); // <--- pass the value that the function needs.
```

Comment: so that's totally different phlilosophy comparing to javascript, isn't it?. Regarding to variable scope.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can get similar behaviour using the [`global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), but it really leads to worse programming practices.